# iOS10 Swift 3 - Simple Drawing Canvas

Tags: ios, swift, canvas, swift3

I'm building an iOS app using Swift 3 and there's a part in my app where I want two "Sign here" fields which will be the canvasses. There will only be one color (black) and a "Reset" button.

So far, I've seen [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/87899/make-simple-drawing-app-uikit-swift), it's on an older version of Swift but someone updated it to Swift 3, [here is the code.](https://github.com/dragosholban/DrawPad)

I copy pasted everything in the `ViewController.swift` file, but I commented out the last two functions `override func prepare` and `ViewController:SettingsViewControllerDelegate` since I didn't need those.

It's working as intended, and the strokes get saved.

However, I have 2 issues with it right now:

1. The lines are drawn to the right of the touch point.
2. I'm unsure on how to make it work for another set of imageviews.

As you can see in this image here, for some reason, the drawn line appears to the right of where I have my cursor. This behavior wasn't the case for the converted original code:

[image]

I am unable to test this on an actual device right now. But this weird behavior wasn't on the converted original code.

Another concern I have is that this is how the code seemed to work:

```
detect touch -> draw on imageview
```

If this is the approach, then how am I supposed to deal with two imageViews if any touch will draw on just one?

I think the approach should have been making a class extended from UIView that overrides the draw function. I saw one such code [here.](https://github.com/nofelmahmood/SmoothDrawing-Swift/blob/master/Drawing/DrawableView.swift) However it's written on old Swift and I don't know how to translate or update it. I tried using the "auto correct" function of XCode but I hit a roadblock.

I have two problems presently:

1. Handling the "offset" between the cursor and where the line is actually drawn, and how to handle more than 1 canvases.
2. Converting [this code to Swift 3](https://github.com/nofelmahmood/SmoothDrawing-Swift/blob/master/Drawing/DrawableView.swift)

Answer (score -1):

Got it. I converted the DrawableView class to Swift 3.

Kindly point out if I did anything wrong that would make the app crash on extended use of w/e.

```
class DrawableView: UIView {

    let path=UIBezierPath()
    var previousPoint:CGPoint
    var lineWidth:CGFloat=1.0
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        previousPoint=CGPoint.zero
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        previousPoint=CGPoint.zero
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let panGestureRecognizer=UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan))
        panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches=1

        self.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        UIColor.green.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
        path.lineWidth=lineWidth
    }

    func pan(panGestureRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer)->Void{
        let currentPoint=panGestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
        let midPoint=self.midPoint(p0: previousPoint, p1: currentPoint)


        if panGestureRecognizer.state == .began{
            path.move(to: currentPoint)
        }
        else if panGestureRecognizer.state == .changed{
            path.addQuadCurve(to: midPoint,controlPoint: previousPoint)
        }

        previousPoint=currentPoint
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    func midPoint(p0:CGPoint,p1:CGPoint)->CGPoint{
        let x=(p0.x+p1.x)/2
        let y=(p0.y+p1.y)/2
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }

}
```